# Is the word “flower” a disyllabic word?

Tags: syllables, triphthongs

At the end of the  word *flower* we have triphthong. So should it be considered a monosyllabic word?

Comment: Depends on who's speaking it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "triphthon". If so, "flower" does not contain a triphthon, as it has only two vowels ("o " and "e ") which are separated by a consonant  ("w").  "Flour" is monosyllabic; "flower" is about a syllable and a half.

Comment: [No, it is **not** a triphthong!](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/12/triphthongs-anyone.html)

Comment: @Brian: most English speakers pronounce *flour* and *flower* ***exactly*** the same. They [used to be](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flour) the same word. They should have the same number of syllables.

Comment: @PeterShor He’s confusing sounds with writing; no profit in that.

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation depends on your dialect. *Flower* is usually pronounced as two syllables, but it can be pronounced as a monosyllable, for example, in the lyrics to some songs, in order to fit them melody.